# PHP SQL Query string concatenation with MySQLi prepared statement

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

What is the correct syntax for concatenating strings and variables in PHP mysqli prepared statements?

The code I have right now is this:

```
        if ($test_stmt2=$mysqli->prepare("UPDATE friends SET friendslist=friendslist+','+? WHERE friendsuserid=? ")) { //Insert userid and frienduserid into friends table
               $test_stmt2->bind_param('si', $friendid, $userid); //Bind parameters (friend user id, your own user id)
               $test_stmt2->execute(); //Execute the prepared query
               echo "success";
        }
```

Basically, I want to get the string in the `friendslist` column, add a comma to it, then add another variable string (`$friendid`) to that cell in the `friends` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need *SQL* concatentation.

However, you shouldn't use it for this purpose. Your database structure is a deadly sin against Holy Normal Form.

Please, do not store comma-separated values in a database cell. Create a distinct *table* to store corresponding values.

```
userid | friendid
     1 |        2
     1 |        3
     1 |        5
     5 |        1
     5 |        2
     2 |       10
```

this way you will need a regular insert query like this:

```
INSERT INTO friendslist SET friendid = ?, userid = ?
```

It will save you **A LOT** of hair in the near future

Comment: yes, i agree that my design is pretty flawed. I want to do it the way you proposed, but how will i know how many columns of friendids to create if people choose different amounts of friends? will i need to constantly expand my table?

Comment: so a different table for every user? then a row for every user's friend?

Comment: just added the table.

Comment: +1. Just for completeness: concatenation in MySQL is easiest using the [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function.